# Where to put wp-config.php when setting up Wordpress for Google App Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow the instructions on https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/. I'm having some doubts at the following step:

[image]

The instructions seem to imply that there should be a `wp-config.php` in the `wordpress` directory. However, as cloned from Github, there is a `wp-config.php` in the main directory above that:

[image]

whereas the `wordpress` directory is empty.

I'm considering two options:
1) Edit the `wp-config.php` and leave it where it is, or
2) Edit the `wp-config.php` and move it to the `wordpress` subdirectory.

Would either of these approaches be correct? Also, are there sufficient files in the starter project to initiate Wordpress, or do I perhaps have to download it myself and put the extracted contents in the `wordpress` directory?

**EDIT**
Thanks again GAEfan for your answer. I've tried again to clone the Github repository, but the `wordpress` directory is still empty:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Website$ git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project.git
Cloning into 'appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project'...
remote: Counting objects: 575, done.
remote: Total 575 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 575
Receiving objects: 100% (575/575), 79.22 MiB | 11.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (317/317), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Website$ cd app*
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project$ cd wordpress
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/wordpress$ ls
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Website/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/wordpress$
```

However, I've noticed that on Github, the `wordpress` directory is itself a link to another Github project:

[image]
[image]

I assume I have to clone all the 'submodules' in their respective directories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wordpress directory should be full of files!  Your app.yaml is set up to look there.  So, the `wp-config.php` should be in it, along with many other files.

Try downloading it again.  My download was: `appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project_build_linux_mac 2`

[image]